# Is it possible to connect Multiple BLE devices to a central device?

Tags: javascript, arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a gateway device something like a raspberry pi and I want to connect multiple BLE devices like Arduino with ble and any other BLE device simultaneously and take data from that . The number of BLE devices maybe above 10 . Will I be able to do this using BLE protocol. Is there any limitations to the number of devices connected to a central?

Answer (score 4):

Per the Bluetooth specification there are no limitations, but each Bluetooth chip has their own limitation. The one embedded onto the Raspberry Pi 3 supports simultaneous 10 connections.

You have a list for some various Bluetooth chips here and their maximum number of simultaneous connections: https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-linux-hci.

Comment: Thanks Emil. So if I connect a central to a peripheral device ,at the same time will I be able to connect that central to another peripheral?